# Importxml fail to extract

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have tried to extract data from the bank portal to google sheets but it always shows the title of table only "Currency Pair   BNP Paribas BUY     BNP Paribas SELL ".

This is the bank portal link that I wish to extract from. https://centric.bnpparibas.com/public/PaymentIndicativeRate/service/indicativeRates/client/VNM

This is the code I have used.
=IMPORTXML("https://centric.bnpparibas.com/public/PaymentIndicativeRate/service/indicativeRates/client/VNM","//tr")

Do you know what stops it from extracting the whole table?